# How to call 2 variable information in perl

Tags: perl

I want to get variable value in subroutine.

```
&file($File1, "TRUE");
&file($File1, "FALSE");

sub file {

  my $File = $_[0];
  my $val = $_[1];
  $TRUElink = Final;

  #I have tried 2 ways:
  $"$val"link;          # 1st
  $($val)link;          # 2nd

}
```

I want to get $TRUElink value to be printed.
I want to get $FALSElink value to be printed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm *guessing* that you want to interpolate `$val` inside double quotes and concatenate with `'link'`

```
print "${val}link";
```

Comment: Side notes; you don't need `&` in front of subroutine call, and `my ($File,$val) = @_;` does the same as above but is more concise and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... I am getting below error message :Scalar found where operator expected at test.pl line 10, near ""Debug: "${val}"
        (Missing operator before ${val}?)
Bareword found where operator expected at test.pl line 10, near "${val}link"
        (Missing operator before link?)

Comment: @user3457622 can you reproduce the problem with exact code, like https://eval.in/384285

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to return $FALSElink or $TRUElink based on the value of $val. Storing a variable name in a variable is problematic (although possible), see [Why it's stupid to `use a variable as a variable name'](http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html). Instead, use a hash

```
my %link = ( TRUE  => 'Final',
             FALSE => 'Whatever',
           );
return ($link{$val})
```

Or, in a binary case, you can use the ternary operator:

```
return ('TRUE' eq $val ? 'Final' : 'Whatever')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do. 'Final' won't have any meaning here.

I'd add a

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
```

to the start of the file which will give more useful diagnostics.

The standard way to get 2 vars into a sub would be something like:

```
my_sub($var1, $var2)
```

and

```
sub my_sub {
  my $v1 = shift;
  my $v2 = shift;

  print "The value of the first passed variable is: $v1";
  print "The value of the first passed variable is: $v1";
}
```